# Why can't I run custom application on my Beaglebone board?

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, buildroot, beagleboard, rootfs

I have cross-compiled the small application for my beaglebone board:

```
/* led_test.c */

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling was done successfully, but if I try to run the application in target board, I get this:

```
# cd /bin/
# ls -la | grep led_test
-rwxr-xr-x    1 default  default      13512 Feb  5  2020 led_test
# led_test 
-sh: ./led_test: not found
```

Why can't I run custom application on my Beaglebone board? Could anyone explain me it, please?

Some information about my environment:

```
1. work-station: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86-64
2. target machine: ARMv7 beaglebone board
3. cross-compiler: gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf
4. I built u-boot and Linux kernel with this toolchain and mounted rootfs via NFS.
```

**UPD 1:**

I tried use this `./led_test` instead `led_test`. It doesn't matter, because my application is placed into `/bin` directory.

Comment: Run `ldd` against your code and, for example, any other executable from the target. Tell us what you see.

Comment: Instead of `ldd`, better use (on the build machine with the cross-compiler): `readelf -d led_test`. It gives a list of shared libraries required for the executable. Check if these are present on your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely your userspace was not built with the cross-toolchain that you compiled your binary with.  Maybe you compiled the kernel with it, but that does not matter, what matters is the rootfs.

Your program is dynamically linked.  When the program runs, the kernel really loads the dynamic linker, and that then maps the executable into the process's address space along with the libraries.

To see the dynamic linker, run `readelf -l` on your host or target system on the binary.  Example:

```
$ readelf -l a.out

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
[... more lines ...]
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3]
[... more output ...]
```

The line with `program interpreter` is the one to look file.  `file` will also give this information.  It's probably the case the the file named here is not preset on your rootfs.  That is the "file not found" that the error is from.

What you need to do is use the correct cross-toolchain (which uses the same C library version) for the rootfs you are using or build a new rootfs with the same toolchain.

Take a look at buildroot for an easy way to make a new, simple, BeagleBone Black rootfs that's way faster and simpler than using Yocto/Poky to make one.

Answer (score 0):

try run by absolute path, or if you in directory run as ./led_test
Also, show output from file
file /bin/led_test
Or run application with gdb

Comment: My app is placed into `/bin`, that's why i can use jush `led_test`, not `./led_test` :)

Comment: # ./led_test 
-sh: ./led_test: not found
# strace ./led_test 
execve("./led_test", ["./led_test"], [/* 16 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++